# Pandas - fill missing column values with corresponding id column values

Tags: python, json, pandas, missing-data

I'm looking to fill missing column values with corresponding code keys from a JSON file, which based on the below code throws me `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`. My code for reading and filling the missing values is below.

```
data = json.load((open('world_bank_projects.json')))

themecodes = json_normalize(data, 'mjtheme_namecode')
    d = themecodes.sort_values('name', na_position='last').set_index('code')['name'].to_dict()
themecodes.loc[themecodes['name'].isnull(), 'name'] = themecodes['code'].map(d)
themecodes.head(20)
    code    name
0   8   Human development
1   11  
2   1   Economic management
3   6   Social protection and risk management
4   5   Trade and integration
5   2   Public sector governance
6   11  Environment and natural resources management
7   6   Social protection and risk management
8   7   Social dev/gender/inclusion
9   7   Social dev/gender/inclusion
10  5   Trade and integration
11  4   Financial and private sector development
12  6   Social protection and risk management
13  6   
14  2   Public sector governance
15  4   Financial and private sector development
16  11  Environment and natural resources management
17  8   
18  10  Rural development
19  7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need if empty values are `None`s or `NaN`s:

```
d = themecodes.sort_values('name', na_position='first').set_index('code')['name'].to_dict()
themecodes.loc[themecodes['name'].isnull(), 'name'] = themecodes['code'].map(d)
```

Or:

```
themecodes['name'] = themecodes['name'].combine_first(themecodes['code'].map(d))
```

---

```
themecodes['name'] = (themecodes.sort_values('name', na_position='last')
                                .groupby('code')['name']
                                .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.iat[0]))
                                .sort_index())
```

---

```
print (themecodes)
    code                                          name
0      8                             Human development
1     11  Environment and natural resources management
2      1                           Economic management
3      6         Social protection and risk management
4      5                         Trade and integration
5      2                      Public sector governance
6     11  Environment and natural resources management
7      6         Social protection and risk management
8      7                   Social dev/gender/inclusion
9      7                   Social dev/gender/inclusion
10     5                         Trade and integration
11     4      Financial and private sector development
12     6         Social protection and risk management
13     6         Social protection and risk management
14     2                      Public sector governance
15     4      Financial and private sector development
16    11  Environment and natural resources management
17     8                             Human development
18    10                             Rural development
19     7                   Social dev/gender/inclusion
```

---

Solution if need replace empty space or some whitespaces:

```
d = themecodes.sort_values('name', na_position='first').set_index('code')['name'].to_dict()
themecodes.loc[themecodes['name'].str.strip() == '', 'name'] = themecodes['code'].map(d)
```

Comment: `d` saves the sorted list of code and name, but neither use of map is filling missing name values...

Comment: @Mr.Jibz - it is dictionary. Can you explain more why it does not work?

Comment: i think use of `d` as a sorted dictionary is clean, and ideally i would fill missing `name` column values in `themecodes` with correposnding keys in `d`

Comment: It seems your empty values are not `NaN`s or `None`s, so was added solution for it.